# Quick AWK Formatting Issue

Tags: awk

I have a line which is reading in a system address, where there can be a wildcard number between 01-47 (the address in specific would be like ring??.host.com)

I'm trying to make awk recognize any of those numbers in a condition argument using regexp

So far this is what I came up with but it seems to not be correct

```
/ring[0-4][0-7].host.com/{ (rest of blah blah blah goes here)}
```

I know that this could give me value 00, but I can safely assume in this instance it will be connected at 01-47.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use some fancy regex, or you could simply *test* if the number is not equal to "00" and less than or equal to 47. With `GNU awk`, perhaps you could try something like this:

```
awk -r '/ring[0-9]{2}\.host\.com/ { string = substr($0, 5, 2); if (string != "00" && string <= 47) print }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want strictly 01 to 47: `(0[1-9]|[123][0-9]|4[0-7])`

Comment: Thank you so much! I found out my CORE issue was something silly (forgot a $ for a field marker) but this helped me error trap!

Answer (score 0):

if "00" is the only case you were worry about, how about:

```
awk '/ring[0-4][0-7]\.host\.com/ && !/ring00\.host\.com/{blahblah}'
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "ring00.host.com
dquote> ring01.host.com
dquote> ring10.host.com"|awk '/ring[0-4][0-7]\.host\.com/ && !/ring00\.host\.com/'
ring01.host.com
ring10.host.com
```

if "39" was valid as well, your regex won't work. you have to extract the 2digits and do something like steve did.